# Laravel: How do I time limit a user to access a Route/Page?

Tags: laravel

Example:
If a user clicks the **'Profile'** button (which redirects to ***/profile*** route), so basically the Web will query like this (**'select * from profile where id=1**).
As far as my boss concern, he don't want the database flooded with query request. He wants a 20 seconds time limit, so if a user clicks the profile again (or refresh) less than 20 sec, then a prompt message would display "Checking your profile, please wait" instead of saying "Hey you are overloading database, please get back after 30sec".

He said that the purpose of this is to protect the database from multiple query request.

The profile is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is using throttle middleware 
In `__contruct` method in your controller. Add these line of code

```
// This mean: 3 hits per 1 minute
$this->middleware('throttle:3,1');
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like charm. Any idea how to change/edit the response "Too many attempt', I want to make it like alert('Too many attempt, retry on 1 minute') on javascript.

Comment: Take look at Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests to get the idea. Then you can write your own middleware with custom message. I've never tried yet :)